# Convert pen and paper math expressions into latex

Tags: math, latex, image-recognition

I've seen some questions about this that are somewhat dated, so I'm asking again in case something new has come up.

**Context**: I'm a student who spends a lot of time making math notes on pen and paper. But I often want to write my notes neatly in latex afterwards, in order to show them to someone else. Right now I have to rewrite everything in latex, which is not terrible, but much slower than doing it on pen and paper, and it is double work. **This really limits how much of my notes I can turn into latex.**

So I am looking for a program that allows you to simply scan the math formulas that you've written on paper, and convert them to latex, which you can then copy paste to TexStudio for instance.

- **It should be quick and easy**, meaning I can quickly scan my notes and get the latex, without much hassle. If it is not quick and easy, I might as well do it manually.
- **Preferably Windows-based**, though if a program on another OS is much better, I would possibly consider using a Virtual OS just for that program.
- **If the program is really good, I'd be willing to spend quite a lot on it**. I'm possibly willing to buy additional necessary hardware for this as well (although of course cheaper is better).

**Are there programs that allow you to convert pen and paper math formulae into latex text in a quick and easy way?**

**Bonus:** If there are similar programs that require a digital stylus instead, that would be a good alternative too.

**EDIT:**
It would perhaps be great if the program works together with a [scanner mouse like this one](https://www.amazon.co.uk/IRIS-457885-Iris-Mouse-Scanner/dp/B00B97SWR6) as can be [seen here in action](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gzzyrdu-i2c).

[Here is an earlier question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/197218/tool-for-converting-maths-writing-to-latex) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/155166/possible-to-convert-math-in-picture-into-latex-how?rq=1) another one from 2014, that didn't get a really good answer, but it's 3 years later now, so...

**EDIT:** I've found [this piece of software](http://www.irislink.com/EN-GB/c1478/Readiris-16---Technical-Support.aspx). The company also makes seemingly very handy scanners. Does anyone have experience with this type of software?